# JQuery Selector for HTML Code which contains same Attributes and dynamic ID

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jquery-selectors

I'm automating some application where it contains same attributes for all the div and with dynamic id's. I'm trying to pick the required div by its text("attribute 'Value'"). Since application in development phase they are changing the text/attribute('Value') every time. So Is there any way to pic required one every time? Thanks for the suggestions :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUYmE.png)

Comment: Why is this tagged java? did you meant javascript?

Comment: I edited my question. You can check now..:)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Post code and HTML as text, properly formatted instead of pictures.

Comment: If you are finding the Div using XPATH then get those by findElements & iterate thn use index. as of now try this & later put validation with exact text

Comment: This will not work because the order of options are changing in different scenarios @saravana

Comment: Have you tried with XPATH? "Options are changing" means "Value" exactly?. based on your image Marked ID of 1st DIV would change frequently but will be available/visible all the time right then you can identify that element [attached image] & traverse into accordingly.